# ES6 Relay list not mapping correctly

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, relay

I have a issue with my map function rendering incorrectly.

The items on content is an array(see below).  And 'content' was passed by its parent with a fragment from a map to switch statement(not displayed here as I don't think it is the problem, but can paste if needed).  The displayed order of the list items from the problem map is Products, About, Contact Us, Products.  So the Home is being skipped as it is first and replaced with the last item 'Products'.  If anymore info is needed let me know, thanks.

```
const PageListItem = (props) => <Link to={props.item.id}>{props.item.value}</Link>;

const PageList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.list}>
      { props.content.items.map( item => <PageListItem key={item._id} item={item} /> ) }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Relay.createContainer(Radium(PageList), {
  fragments: {
    content: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Content {
        items {
          _id
          id
          value
        }
      }
    `,
  }
});
```

The content array of data being mapped (From mongoose)

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("920005cd1a38532d14349240"), 
"items" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57102a0ad9601e34489223c1"), 
        "value" : "Home", 
        "id" : "110005cd1a38532d14349240", 
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57102a0ad9601e34489223c0"), 
        "value" : "About", 
        "id" : "120005cd1a38532d14349240", 
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57102a0ad9601e34489223bf"), 
        "value" : "Contact Us", 
        "id" : "130005cd1a38532d14349240", 
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57102a0ad9601e34489223be"), 
        "value" : "Products", 
        "id" : "110005cd1a38532d14349240", 
    }
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to Relay object identification. More about it is available in the [specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm).

If you're using [graphql-relay-js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) on the server side, the exposed objects (GraphQLObject types) should have an associated `id` property, which is treated as local ID. `graphql-relay-js` has helper function [`globalIdField`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js#object-identification) to translate this local ID to a global ID. This global ID is used by Relay on the client side to differentiate among the different pieces of data.

As @tomáš-holub already pointed out, the local IDs for Home and Products are the same. As Products came later in the list, Home got overridden.

To be on the safe side, I usually add `id` property to objects/data, which are eventually exposed as GraphQL objects. When MongoDB is used, these local `id`s are usually `_id`s (`xyz.id = abc._id.toHexString()`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **id** of your items "Home" and "Products" are the same. If you change one id, it should work fine.

Comment: omg I thought I tried that first with it still not working.  Why would that matter tho as the _id's are different and used for the key.  Do you think this has to do with Link having a to={props.item.id} identical to another?
 
I still would like for it to be able to map identical values (_id will be unique)

Comment: I tried to clone the functionality here: [link](http://jsbin.com/gusomed/24/edit?html,js,output)
It seems to work as expected, i.e. Link (in this case MyLink) has the expected id (i.e. two ids are the same) and the value is the correct one.
If it doesn't help, try to output the parameters of the functions with alert(JSON.stringify(props))...

Comment: First off thanks for putting so much effort to help.  So I have been trying to get it working for a while now and still is not working properly.  It keeps rendering Products twice.  It complains about the key's being the same still even tho the _id's are different.  When I print the JSON for PageList it pulls Products, About, Contact Us, Products.  The PageListItem is rendering what it is given out fine.  So the pagelist should be the problem, however when I look at the query in GraphiQL it is returning the correct list.  So the problem could be the PageList query in relay or its a map

Comment: The thing that boggles my mind right now is if I remove the id field completely from being rendered/queried and only use '_id' and 'value', it still says I have identical keys.  Then if i go into the database and change products 'id' to be different like you first said it works fine... (while still not using id in any child components)

Comment: So I figured out a solution.  I think graphql was confusing the 'id' field with a graphql id.  I put the string that was in the 'id' field into one called 'key' and everything works fine while leaving 'id' empty/null. Weird thing is if i use 'id' with it being null graphql doesnt get it confused in the list.  Note for others who experience this: do not name a field id as graphql might confuse it. Do you think i should create a new answer for this?